# Critical points of $(x^2+y^2)e^{y^2-x^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\frac{df}{dx} = 2xe^{y^2-x^2}(1-x^2-y^2) = 0.$

$\frac{df}{dy} = 2ye^{y^2-x^2}(1+x^2+y^2) = 0.$

So, $2xe^{y^2-x^2}(1-x^2-y^2) = 2ye^{y^2-x^2}(1+x^2+y^2)$.

$x(1-x^2-y^2) = y(1+x^2+y^2)$

$x-x^3-xy^2 = y + x^2y + y^3$

Is the guessing the values of the variables the only way of solving this? With $y = 0$ and I can already figure out that $x = 0$, $1$ or $-1$ but It's bothering me how I had to randomly guess that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $e^{y^2 - x^2}(1 + x^2 + y^2)$ can *never* be zero, so there is only one way that $\frac{df}{dy} = 0$ can hold.

Answer (score 3):

You had a good step in doing: $\frac{df}{dx} = 2xe^{y²-x²}(1-x²-y²) = 0$ and $\frac{df}{dy} = 2ye^{y²-x²}(1+x²+y²) = 0$.

Now, you don't need to equate the two...rather think of how to solve each individual equation on its own.

**Hint:** Think of how to solve the equations individually, then you will be fine!